# nullPointerException I cannot figure out in Java generic class

Tags: java, nullpointerexception

I am trying to write program and keep getting a nullPointerException when I call a particular method, what does this mean ?

Comment: This question and the code looks extremely familiar. I've seen this definitely before a few hours ago, but can't find it now... It was answered there.

Comment: @stackoflow, Hm.. Have you recreate topic and delete previous? (-1 until answer)

Comment: This question is extremely similar to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5185577/java-generic-arguments/5185607

Comment: This is not homework, and yes this is a previously submitted topic - I phrased my last question badly, it got spammed, I spoke to a mod who deleted it so that it wouldn't confuse any people trying to learn from it. Acceptable answer ?

Comment: -1 undoned as answer provided.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it should be

```
private int size; //non static

private static <S extends Comparable<S>> MyList<S> leftHalf(MyList<S> list) {
    MyList<S> leftSide = new MyList<S>();
    int middle = list.size() /2;
    for (int countToMiddle = 0; countToMiddle < middle; countToMiddle++) {
        leftSide.addEnd(list.head());
    }

    return leftSide;
}
```

if no, please provide more information about what this method should do.

**upd:**
construction issue

```
public MyList() {   //takes no arguments
    nodes = null;
}
public MyList(T... args) {  //takes any number of arguments
    this();
    for(T t : args){
        add(t);
    }
}
```

**upd:**
addEnd issue

```
public void addEnd(T item) {
    if (nodes == null) {
        nodes = new NodesList<T>(item, null);
        return;
    }
    if (nodes.tail == null) {
        nodes.tail = new NodesList<T>(item, null);
    } else {
        nodes.tail == new NodesList<T>(nodes.tail, item);
    }
}
```

Comment: This method should split the list into two lists, in the first(leftSize) it will contain the elements from 0 to n/2, in the second, rightSide, it will contain the elements from n/2 to n.

Unfortunately my implementation does not seem to work, as, when I call 'MyList list = new MyList<Long>( 1L, 2L, 3L ); //3 entries
list.print();', I get the error cannot find symbol
symbol  : constructor MyList(long,long,long)

Comment: @stackoflow, I think, this method should do exactly what you want) , correct? Optionally you can remove static modifier and list argument.

Comment: @stackoflow, about constructor : you should create constructor with _vararg_ to do things like this. It's other question)

Comment: I believe it should, by my logic, which is often incorrect! I cannot test it, however. Unfortunately I am still having the error that when I call the MyList constructor, I get the message "cannot find symbol
symbol  : constructor MyList(long,long,long)".

Comment: @Stas , could you please elaborate on using vararg ? Thanks.

Comment: Also, when called using ints, I receive the error java.lang.NullPointerException
 at MyList.addEnd(MyList.java:42)
 at MyList.leftHalf(MyList.java:88)
 at MyList.sort(MyList.java:55)

Comment: @stackoflow, it throws exception because when temp null. it goes to second expression, and throwing exception by trying accessing field at null object (temp.tail).  Also, see updated answer.

Comment: @Stas Kurilin: Thank you for the help. Do you know how I would be able to fix the nullPointerException ?

Comment: Also, if I add a second item to the list using addEnd, it deletes the originally added item i.e if I call addEnd twice, it overwrites the previous value. Edit : Changed my && to an || and this problem fixed itself.

Comment: @Stas Kurilin, thank you very much for the response, unfortunately when I try and compile this I get an error that it cannot find the symbol tail when I try and call tail.addEnd(item); at the end of your method, I've tried changing this to nodes.tail.addEnd(item, null) and had no luck. Thanks again.

Comment: After your edit, I am getting the error cannot find symbol
symbol  : method addEnd(T)
location: class NodeList<T>, I can't think of any easy way to solve this, sorry to be a nuisance but could you help with this please ? :) Thank you !

Comment: @stackoflow, I do not see any source of this problem.

Comment: @Stas, ah, got it, you got nodes.tail and item the wrong way around ! Thank you very much for the help :)

Comment: @Stas Kurilin, Sorry to annoy again, but unfortunately this implementation of addEnd does not work, it does not tag an element on to the end of the list, instead it inserts one in the second position in the list. For example, if I call list.add(1); list.add(0); list.addEnd(2);, it should give me a list of 0, 1 ,2 in that order. In this case, it gives me a list of 0, 2, 1. The sorting algorithm is also not working, though I realise I need to do work on this! Thank you

Comment: @stackoflow, Yeah. You are right . Just create new constructor with takes list and then Last item.

Comment: @Stas Kurilin - Is that not really inefficient ? I figured that would be a method, but there must be a better way ! :)

Comment: @stackoflow, to create your own List is really inefficient) As I understand you try to implement list by `Lisp` way or smt like that. There was function (I do not remember name exactly, it can be `cons` ) to create such structures from (list and element) and (element and list). So it is normal)